# Symfony2 wildcard routing

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-routing

I'm trying to create a special route that handles confirmation of a certain action. For instance, if I'm trying to access a route `/admin/user/1/delete`, I want to go to a different route first to show a special html page that confirms they want to complete an action (ie. confirm/admin/user/1/delete) and on the page there's a confirm button that goes to the route and a go back button that redirects to the referrer.

In the example below, is there a way to allow {route} to be anything and pass that into a twig page?

```php
/**
* @Route("/confirm/{route}", name="confirm_dialog")
* @param type $route
*/
public function confirmAction($route)
{
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass your confirmation route in the querystring E.g. /confirm?route=/admin/user/1/delete - seems simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cookbook covering this specific use case:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

> By default, the Symfony Routing component requires that the parameters match the following regex path: "[^/]+". This means that all characters are allowed except "/".
>   You must explicitly allow "/" to be part of your parameter by specifying a more permissive regex path: ".+"

```
/**
* @Route("/confirm/{route}", name="confirm_dialog", requirements={"route"=".+"})
* @param type $route
*/
public function confirmAction($route)
{
    // ...
}
```

But I would not recommend the pattern you are trying to use.
I would recommend to have the same route "*/admin/user/1/delete*" using **GET** to display a confirmation form and using **POST** to perform the deletion.
If you don't want to repeat the code for asking confirmation, you can always extract that specific code.

Comment: Thanks Geoffroy, That's what I was looking for, just didn't know what to call it. I was thinking about doing it the way you mentioned, but then I would need to have two methods for each route which could be in the 100+ range.

Comment: you don't need to have different methods, just check if it's a POST in the action